# What is the solution?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

What is a word made up of 4 letters,

yet is also made up of 3,

Sometimes is written with 9 letters, and then with 4,

Rarely consists of 6,

and never is written with 5 ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because in the intended 'solution', there is no question to answer, no puzzle to solve.

Comment: @Deusovi there a solution, But I won't write it here.

Comment: Agreed to close.  Once the puzzle has been solved, there's no specific way to answer.

Comment: I think the title should be interpreted in a way that will give a unique answer to this question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Can I say that:

> The question is "What is **the solution**?"
>  And following the pattern in the clue (each number describes the number of letters in the first word in the phrase), then:
>
> ```
> The solution is a phrase made up of 11 letters
> ```
>
> (space is not a letter)

Answer (score 8):

This is the solution :

> Each number of letter concerns a word of the sentence :
>  What has 4 letters
>  yet has 3
>  Sometimes 9
>  then 4
>  Rarely 6
>  never 5

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't manage to put it in a spoiler I don't know why it won't work on multiple lines... I hope people won't mind

Comment: nice observation.

Comment: I guess the answer then is 8? Or what does your solution solve?

Comment: I admitted the OP is like me a non english speaker, and sometimes you have to take things not too litteraly so I answered the way he wanted to I guess.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is

> What

As stated in the title

> "What" is the solution

Answer (score 0):

What is the solution?

> The solution is a word made up of 8 letters.