# 4, 9 or 5 letters?

Tags: wordplay

I recently came across a nice quickie, so here it goes:

> What has 4 letters, sometimes has 9 letters and never has 5 letters.

Sorry, if it is on the site already - I couldn't find it here

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Can't believe I missed these typos - thanks for edit

Comment: It's already answered here: https://www.quora.com/What-has-4-letters-sometimes-9-letters-but-never-has-5-letters

Comment: Are we supposed to answer the question in the title?

Comment: I was tempted to post this riddle two days ago as well, but it turned out to be posted already here: [What is the solution?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24769/what-is-the-solution)

Answer (score 8):

The answer is

> Correct

Has four letters

> "what" has four letters

Sometimes has nine letters

> "sometimes" has nine letters

Never has five letters

> "never" has five letters

Answer (score 5):

> **What** : 4 letters, **sometimes** : 9 letters, **never** : 5 letters, so is the answer 'correct'?

Comment: Although your answer was posted a bit earlier (14 seconds, so I guess it's no big deal anyway), I believe @benzene's answer was more complete.